# row in gridview doesnt replace from existing row when updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I am workin on Leave Management of Employees currently. There is 2 Grid View one for Manager which displays the Leaves Applied by particular Employee that contains ull leave Details. There is Status column in GridView which shows Pending once leave is applied. And once Manager logs in and clicks on Update column which is an Hyperlink he will redirect into another page showing details of the leave and he can Accept or Reject the leave. Once he does any of the two ,gridview will get updated setting status=accepted or rejected from Pending.

In another gridview which is for Employee which shows all the leaves he/she has applied. even ths grid view has got status and once he applies it will show Pending and once Manager Accepts/rejects it shows either respectively.

There is Hyperlink column too in Employee GridView when he clicks that he will get redirected to another page showing the details of the leave he has applied and it has got a button to Reapply for the leave.

This Reapply is only or those leave which is rejected or in pending status.

The problem is when Employee Reapplies may be by editing the details or with same details for the Rejected Leave GridView of Employee gets Updated but it doesnt get replace with the particular Rejected row for which he has reapplied. It will take new Leave Request.  I need Rejected Leave Request to be Replaced with ReApplied Leave Request setting the Status from Rejected to Pending.

Sorry or the long post but i wanted to explain whole scenario. Bare with this. :)

cs code for ReAply

```
   protected void BtnReApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();

        int Flag = 0;

        LblLoggedInUser.Text = Session["EmpName"].ToString();
        objc.LoggedInUser = LblLoggedInUser.Text;

        objc.TypeofLeave = LblTypeofLeave.Text;

        string date;
        date = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtBeginDate.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

        objc.BeginDate = dt;
        objc.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtEndDate.Text);
        objc.Description = TxtDescription.Text;
        objc.NumofDays = Convert.ToInt32(TxtNumofDays.Text);
        objc.Status = LblStatus.Text;

        int X = obj.InsertLeave(objc);
        {
            if (X >= 0)
            {
                Flag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Flag = 0;

            }
        }

        if (Flag == 1)
        {
            LblSuccess.Visible = true;
            LblSuccess.Text = "Data Added Successfully and Leave Application Succesfully Sent";
        }
        else
        {
            LblErr.Visible = true;
            LblErr.Text = "Failed To Add Data and Send Leave Request!!!";
        }

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add("");
        message.Subject = "Leave Request";
        message.From = new MailAddress("");
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        LblLoggedInUser.Text = Session["EmpName"].ToString();
        objc.LoggedInUser = LblLoggedInUser.Text;

        TxtManager.Text = Session["Manager"].ToString();
        objc.Manager = TxtManager.Text;

        objc.TypeofLeave = LblTypeofLeave.Text;

        objc.NumofDays = Convert.ToInt32(TxtNumofDays.Text.Trim());

        message.Body = "<span style = font-family:Arial,font-size:10pt>";
        message.Body += "Hello <b>" + Session["Manager"].ToString() + "</b>,<br /><br />";
        message.Body += "<b>" + Session["EmpName"].ToString() + "</b>" + "&nbsp; has requested" + "<b>" + "&nbsp;" + LblTypeofLeave.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;for" + "<b>" + "&nbsp;" + TxtNumofDays.Text + "&nbsp;" + "</b><br />";
        message.Body += "day/days, kindly login to the portal to Accept or Reject it";
        message.Body += "<br />";
        message.Body += "<br />";
        message.Body += "Thank You.<br />";
        message.Body += "</span>";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("");
        smtp.Send(message);

        LblTypeofLeave.Text = "";
        TxtBeginDate.Text = "";
        TxtEndDate.Text = "";
        TxtDescription.Text = "";
        TxtNumofDays.Text = "";
        LblStatus.Text = "";
    }
```

Row DataBound Code for Employee GridView

```
protected void GridViewLeaveHistory_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink ViewDetails = e.Row.FindControl("ViewDetails") as HyperLink;
            ViewDetails.NavigateUrl = "ReApply.aspx?LeaveID=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ((Label)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("Description")).Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word");
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRow pr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

            string status = Convert.ToString(pr["Status"]);

            if (status == "Accepted")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
                e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if(status == "Rejected")
                e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                if (status == "Pending")
                e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is GridView Code for Employee

```
protected void GrdLeaveHistory()
    {
        MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();
        {
            objc.EmpName = Convert.ToString(Session["EmpName"]);
            DataSet GrdLH = obj.GrdLeaveHistory(objc);
            DataView GrdLeaveH = new DataView();
            GrdLeaveH.Table = GrdLH.Tables[0];
            GridViewLeaveHistory.DataSource = GrdLeaveH;
            GridViewLeaveHistory.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put ths code in row data bound

```
if (status == "ReApplied")
                    e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                if (status == "Leave Cancellation Requested")
                    e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
```

in page load of reapply page put this

```
 if (LblStatus.Text == "Rejected")
        {
            BtnCancelLeave.Visible = false;
        }
```